# Best way to get two columns from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have taken over a project and found a table that has the following video and video title fields in it (why they didn't create a separate linked table is beyond me):

```
[VIDEOURL]
[VIDEOTITLE]
[COUKVIDEO1URL]
[COUKVIDEO2URL]
[COUKVIDEO3URL]
[COUKVIDEO4URL]
[COUKVIDEO1TITLE]
[COUKVIDEO2TITLE]
[COUKVIDEO3TITLE]
[COUKVIDEO4TITLE]
```

Can this query be improved to get a single list of titles and urls from the above fields:

```
SELECT 
    t.VIDEOURL, 
    t.VIDEOTITLE 
FROM
(
    SELECT VIDEOURL, VIDEOTITLE FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    UNION
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO1URL] AS VIDEOURL, [COUKVIDEO1TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    UNION
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO2URL] AS VIDEOURL, [COUKVIDEO2TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    UNION
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO3URL] AS VIDEOURL, [COUKVIDEO3TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    UNION
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO4URL] AS VIDEOURL, [COUKVIDEO4TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
) t
WHERE t.VIDEOURL != ''
AND t.VIDEOTITLE != ''
```

Comment: this schema makes me shiver..

Comment: Can you modify or add a new table? I'm not good in SQL, but I really feel that the real problem is not the query but the table. I know that sometime you can't modify existing table or have some limitations of some kinds.

Comment: @Marc-Andre unfortunately not, the data is being replicated from some internal systems and I am unable to touch that or the db server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no telling how the database will optimize the query plan for this, but I would expect that the best query plan would involve applying the predicates to the tables before the union is done. Doing a UNION of multiple small result sets would be more efficient than doing a union on large sets and then filtering the results.

The UNION operation requires a lot of scanning because UNION is also a DISTINCT process (you only have one record of each value in the result).

So, two things.

If you are sure that the values in in a column-pair will not also be in any of the other column-pairs, then you can replace the `UNION` with the faster `UNION ALL`.

If you are sure that a column-pair is unique, or empty, then you can avoid the DISTINCT process completely.

I would write the query as:

```
    SELECT VIDEOURL,
           VIDEOTITLE
    FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    WHERE [VIDEOURL] != ''
      AND [VIDEOTITLE] != ''
  UNION ALL
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO1URL] AS VIDEOURL,
           [COUKVIDEO1TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE
    FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    WHERE [COUKVIDEO1URL] != ''
      AND [COUKVIDEO1TITLE] != ''
  UNION ALL
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO2URL] AS VIDEOURL,
           [COUKVIDEO2TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE
    FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    WHERE [COUKVIDEO2URL] != ''
      AND [COUKVIDEO2TITLE] != ''
  UNION ALL
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO3URL] AS VIDEOURL,
           [COUKVIDEO3TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE
    FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    WHERE [COUKVIDEO3URL] != ''
      AND [COUKVIDEO3TITLE] != ''
  UNION ALL
    SELECT [COUKVIDEO4URL] AS VIDEOURL,
           [COUKVIDEO4TITLE] AS VIDEOTITLE
    FROM [VincentV5].[dbo].[MARCMSITEMPRESENTATION]
    WHERE [COUKVIDEO4URL] != ''
      AND [COUKVIDEO4TITLE] != ''
```

If values in one column-pair can appear in other column pairs, then change the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

If the values can be duplicated in a column-pair, then add `DISTINCT` to each `SELECT`.

Do both `DISTINCT` and `UNION ALL` if you need to.

The idea is to make the data as small as possible before you start doing the big merging processes.